# jq query to convert nested json to csv

Tags: json, jq, export-to-csv

I am new to jq and try to process a nested json file and convert it to csv format. The sample nested json file is composed of three levels as below:

```
{
level1-label: {
    level2-text1 : {
        level3-label1: value1,
        level3-label2: value2,
        level3-label3: value3
    },
    level2-text2 : {
        level3-label1: value4,
        level3-label2: value5,
        level3-label3: value6
    }
}
}
```

Desired output

```
level2, level3-label1, level3-label2, level3-lable3

level2-text1, value1, value2, value3
level2-text2, value4, value5, value6
```

Having research for many hours, it seems the function "to_entries" may be the proper solution. I could finally come up with two queries to process level2 and level3 data as an array but could not go further.

Query with result of arrays just containing level2 keys

```
jq -r ".level1-label | to_entries | map([.key])" input.json
```

Query with result of arrays just containing level3 keys and values

```
jq -r ".level1-label | to_entries | map(.value)" input.json
```

Please advice the direction to combine the above queries or other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use | (Pipe) operator to pass the output of one command as an input to another command. You need this to combine both the queries:

```
jq -r '.["level1-label"] | to_entries[] | [.key] + (.value | to_entries[] | [.key, .value]) | @csv' input.json
```

should work on JSON structure:

```json
{
    "level1-label": {
        "level2-text1": {
            "level3-label1": "value1",
            "level3-label2": "value2",
            "level3-label3": "value3"
        },
        "level2-text2": {
            "level3-label1": "value4",
            "level3-label2": "value5",
            "level3-label3": "value6"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried with error: jq: error: level1-label/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:

Comment: @Cloudwind This is because your JSON is not formatted for strings. Edited the JSON structure to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_entries` to access the `.key` while iterating through the values under `.value`, collect everything into a new array `[…]`, and have `@csv` create from it the CSV formatting:

```bash
jq -r '."level1-label" | to_entries[] | [.key, .value[]] | @csv' input.json
```

```
"level2-text1","value1","value2","value3"
"level2-text2","value4","value5","value6"
```

Comment: Great thanks. It is working like a charm. Besides, I try to select some row(s) from the csv data, like first item equal to "level2-text2". I can get them by pipe the whole output to 'findstr "level2-text2"'. As an alternative, I try to use the select function but failure again: jq -r '."level1-label" | to_entries[] | [.key, .value[]] | select (.key=="level2-text2" ) | @csv' input.json
Any idea?

Comment: @Cloudwind After `[.key, .value[]]`, all you have is an array with values, so using `.key` will run empty at that point. Move it one place to the left: `… | to_entries[] | select(.key == "level2-text2") | [.key, .value[]] | …`.

Comment: @Cloudwind. I can't reproduce your error. Firstly, make sure your input is valid JSON (if `jq . input.json` runs into issues it is not - see the following demos how your sample input should look like). [This](https://jqplay.org/s/rPHPU113Iqr) is a demo of how my response works, and [here](https://jqplay.org/s/c_MR3IXOZEt) is the same with your filter for `"level2-text2"` added as described in the previous comment.

Comment: Thanks. It is working fine. May be due to hidden code in the json file.